# sharing a quote on twitter using window.open() method

Tags: javascript, twitter

I am creating an app which randomly generates a quote at the click of a button. I want the user to be able to either share this quote on twitter or facebook, but that is where the issue is arising.

HTML:

```
<div class="row">

<div id="quoteBox" class="col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3">

<p><span id="famousQuote">"Nothing in life is to be feared; it is only to be understood. Now is the time to understand more so that we may fear less."</span></p>

<i id="fbicon" class="fa fa-facebook-official fa-3x" aria-hidden="true" style="color:white"></i>
<i id="twitterShare" class="fa fa-twitter fa-3x" aria-hidden="true" style="color:white"></i>


</div>

<div class="row">

<div class="col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-4">
<button id="generateQuote" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Change Quote</button> 

</div>


</div>

</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
document.getElementById("twitterShare").addEventListener("click", function(){
var url ="https://twitter.com/intent.tweet";
var text = document.getElementById("famousQuote").value;
window.open(url+"?text="+text);
        })
```

However, when I do click on the twitter icon, a link shows saying "Sorry, that page doesn’t exist!"

Evidently, one of the things I am getting wrong here is the URL, or perhaps the way I have written it.

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `value` is only for form controls elements, not content elements

Answer (score 1):

You need to encode the URL params and also use a different URL:

```
document.getElementById("twitterShare").addEventListener("click", function(){
  var url ="https://twitter.com/share?url=" + encodeURIComponent(document.location);
  var text = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("famousQuote").innerText);
  window.open(url + "&text=" + text);
})
```

Comment: Hi Nick, many thanks for the response. It has helped at least bring up the twitter page and loaded the "Whats happening?" tweet message box, but within the box instead of the quote appearing the text is showing as "undefined"

Comment: If you do `console.log(encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("famousQuote").innerText))` what does it output?